# LDAP - Forward OU to remote LDAP OU

Tags: ldap, remote

i've been looking for a solution to forward a OU request to a remote LDAP OU.

- dc=domain

  - ou=accounts

    - ou=local-accounts

      - cn=local-user
    - ou=remote-accounts

      - *ALL OBJECTS FROM PRE DEFINED REMOTE LDAP*

The main problem is that i have to forward the whole user authentication to a different server.

- We sync all Users from AD1 to "ou=local-accounts,ou=accounts,dc=domain" and authenticate them with SASL against the AD1.
- We wants to forward all authentication processes in "ou=remote-accounts,ou=accounts,dc=domain" to AD2 without SASL.

I hope you guys can help me with this problem.

Kind regards,
Marvyn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using an meta backend and the rwm overlay. Heres the slapd.conf which explains it all.

```
overlay            rwm
rwm-suffixmassage "ou=remote-accounts,ou=accounts,dc=domain" "ou=accounts,dc=meta"

database        bdb
directory       /var/lib/ldap
suffix          "dc=domain"
rootdn          "cn=root,dc=domain"
rootpw          root
index           objectclass eq
index           uid eq,sub
lastmod         off
readonly        off


database        meta
suffix          "dc=local"
readonly        off
lastmod         off

uri            "ldap://remote.ldap/ou=accounts,dc=meta"
suffixmassage   "ou=accounts,dc=meta" "ou=accounts,dc=remote-domain"
idassert-bind   bindmethod=simple
   binddn="DN-TO-ADMIN-USER-AT-REMOTE-DOMAIN"
   credentials="PASSWORD"
   mode=none
   flags=non-prescriptive
idassert-authzFrom "dn.exact:cn=root,dc=meta"
```